# Deserialize dynamic objects without 'Value'

Tags: c#, json, dynamic

I have class and I'm deserializing like

```
  class MyClass
    {
        public string Property { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string entities = "{\"Property\":\"\"}";
        var entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(entities);
        var propertyValue = entity.Property;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

It's working fine. I can get property of class. Now, I want to deserialize as dynamic:

```
        string entities = "{\"Property\":\"\"}";
        var entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(entities);
        var propertyValue = entity.Property.Value;
```

In dynamic, I should should do `entity.Property.Value`. How to get property without 'Value'? And also how to deserialize list of dynamic objects and get their properties without using 'Value'?

**Edit:**

I found interesting thing. When I'm getting `entity.Property` using `var` type of variable becomes `JValue` and when I'm getting it using `string` type of variable it becomes `string`

Comment: you must get the property value witout `Value`. The use of `Value`is for nullables fields

Comment: @juanpe, As you see property is not nullable. entity.Property is JValue type here

Comment: @Dllshod since it is not nullable, you must access its value through the name of the property, without using `Value`. `entity.Property` gives you back its value

Comment: @juanpe As I said, entity.Property is not string type. It is JValue type.Look, I putted  screen

Comment: @Dllshod See in the screen shot the value of the Type Property is String

Comment: @juanpe Yes, entity.Property.Value.GetType().Name is string, but entity.Property.GetType().Name is JValue

Comment: @dllshod Sorry, my English is low. Maybe I'm not understanding well your question.